# transferring data between two components in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I learning Vuejs

Me need pass search variable from App.vue in to Coins.vue

My example in this bin https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-L-DV0CWu7HMDPJj4191

how right make it ?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of Vuex - https://github.com/vuejs/vuex
Or properties - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-with-Props